# jszip image is saving but image size showing as zero byte

Tags: javascript

Images are saved properly but their size comes out to be zero bytes help me out please.

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#submitId', function() {
        var zip = new JSZip();
        var file = $('#pan')[0].files[0];
        zip.file($('#pan')[0].files[0].name, getBase64(file), {
            base64 : true
        });
        zip.generateAsync({
            type : "blob"
        }).then(function(content) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file1', content);
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'URL',
                data : fd,
                processData : false,
                contentType : false
                }).done(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: why did you not post the code here?

Comment: `Images are saved properly but their size comes out to be zero bytes` - that sounds like a contradiction ... based on the code you posted as an answer in an old question (??) ... the problem seems to be with your **server side** code

Comment: I am not able to post here showing some error while posting.

Comment: Included the code OP claims he / she was unable to post here.